# bootbox compilation error in typescript

Tags: typescript, bootbox

When I import bootbox.d.ts (https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/bootbox/bootbox.d.ts) as a typescript reference, i get the following error:

Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target:
    Type '{ label: string; }' is missing property 'class' from type 'BootboxHandler'

This is the code from the bootbox.d.ts file throwing the error

```
interface BootboxHandler {
    label: string;
    class: string;
    callback: (result?: any) => void;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that the properties are not set as optional.  The bootbox.d.ts should have questionmarks.

```
interface BootboxHandler {
    label: string;
    class?: string;
    callback?: (result?: any) => void;
 }
```